# What is the meaning of "...up close they turn cold"

Tags: meaning-in-context

I posted a question [here](https://biology.stackexchange.com/questions/61156/why-females-dont-have-much-sexual-desire-when-compare-to-males), & somebody posted their [comment](https://biology.stackexchange.com/questions/61156/why-females-dont-have-much-sexual-desire-when-compare-to-males#comment112142_61156) on it.

> Males often have more desire from a distance, but up **close they turn
>   cold**. The opposite applies to females.

What does turn cold means ? Is it another meaning to death?

I used to follow Tom & Jerry shows, if some character dead their eyes usually shows **turn cold**.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See [cold](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/cold): "7. adjective - A cold person does not show much emotion, especially affection, and therefore seems unfriendly and unsympathetic. If someone's voice is cold, they speak in an unfriendly unsympathetic way." – user3169

desire : hot :: lack of desire : cold. To "turn cold" means all of the ardor goes away. – Tᴚoɯɐuo

So, the meaning is that *men are may be strongly (sexually) attracted (to a woman) who is distant from them, but when they get close (physically or emotionally) to the woman they become less (sexually) attracted to her. For women the opposite is true.*

In Tom and Jerry, there is a scene in which the Dog has been given sleeping medicine by Tom, and his eyes show "Out Cold" meaning fast asleep. That's not directly related to this sense.